# How to retrieve data from multiple tables in MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

**TLDR: Please point me to the SIMPLEST tutorial for my problem. I have read many tutorials but all they did was confuse me more.**

I have three tables.

1. students (has a row of id and name)
2. courses (has a row of id and name)
3. courses_students

The third table to link the two was created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE courses_students (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    student_id INT(6) REFERENCES students(id),
    course_id INT(6) REFERENCES courses(id)
);
```

Then I add a simple data like this:

```
INSERT INTO courses_students (course_id, student_id) VALUES (2, 3);
```

The 2 and 3 are ids in the courses and students tables, respectively. How do I retrieve the information for these ids *(2 from the courses table, and 3 from the students tables)* using mysqli+PHP statements?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. And note that the number in parentheses following an INT declaration is almost meaningless and probably best omitted.

Comment: _"Please point me to the SIMPLEST tutorial for my problem"_ - Please read: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - _"asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty straight forward, there are many ways, here is the simplest one (assuming you've "established" a connection as described here https://www.php.net/pdo.connections):

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("
            SELECT s.id AS studentId, s.name AS studentName, c.id AS courseId, c.name AS courseName
            FROM courses_students AS cs
            LEFT JOIN students AS s ON s.id = cs.student_id
            LEFT JOIN courses AS c ON c.id = cs.course_id
        ");

$records = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

That's getting a bit more complex when you need to query with parameters - then you should read a bit more about bindings, but the general idea is like the following code:

```
// Preparing the statement.
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
            SELECT s.id AS studentId, s.name AS studentName, c.id AS courseId, c.name AS courseName
            FROM courses_students AS cs
            LEFT JOIN students AS s ON s.id = cs.student_id
            LEFT JOIN courses AS c ON c.id = cs.course_id
            WHERE cs.student_id = :studentId
            AND cs.course_id = :courseId
        ");

// Binding and executing the statement.
$stmt->execute([
    'studentId' => 3,
    'courseId' => 2
]);

$records = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: It was confusing a bit with the AS but then I was able to figure it out once I removed the AS and changed the table names to the full ones! Thanks!

Comment: Sure, the reason I gave aliases (using the AS) allowed me to write a shorthand version of the query you would like to have, but as far as it works for you, that's great!